# ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’

Tags: r

I just try to install the 'Rsymphony' package and it failed and the error indicator says

> Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
>   See https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony’

Addition: my platform is mac os.

Comment: Have you installed the Symphony libraries and headers?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, open terminal and type:

`curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /`

reference to [Rcpp, RcppArmadillo and OS X Mavericks "-lgfortran" and "-lquadmath" error](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/)

Comment: Can you explain how this is relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: might need `curl -OL` according to here: https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2/issues/189